# Removing a block of text (saved in variable) inside file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

This may sound like a question that'd be answered multiple times on google, and it is. But strangely enough, I can't find any answer that actually works (I'm a bit suprised by it)!

Lets say I have a text file with something in it, and a variable inside a script that has the exact information that needs to be removed from the file. That's it.

Most of the values for the variables are removed (because they're api tokens or something similar)
This is the text file (`advancedplexapivar.txt`):

```
[Aimee]
filelocation=""
datesetup=""
checkdeluge="false"
showtoken="true"
autobackup="false"
logging="true"
logfolder=""
plexapitoken=""
ipplexserver="192.168.2.15"
sonarrapitoken=""
ipsonarrserver="192.168.2.15"
sonarrport="8005"

[Dee]
filelocation=""
datesetup="dd-mm-yyyy"
checkdeluge="false"
showtoken="true"
autobackup="false"
logging="true"
logfolder=""
plexapitoken=""
ipplexserver="192.168.2.15"
sonarrapitoken=""
ipsonarrserver="192.168.2.15"
sonarrport="8005"
```

Inside the script, I set a variable to what needs to be removed:

```bsh
oldvalue=$(very long command)
```

An example of the value of `$oldvalue`:

```bsh
echo $oldvalue ->
[Dee]
filelocation=""
datesetup="dd-mm-yyyy"
checkdeluge="false"
showtoken="true"
autobackup="false"
logging="true"
logfolder=""
plexapitoken=""
ipplexserver="192.168.2.15"
sonarrapitoken=""
ipsonarrserver="192.168.2.15"
sonarrport="8005"
```

My plan was to do the following but that doesn't work because of the multiple lines:

```bsh
sed -i "s/$oldvalue//g" advancedplexapivar.txt ->
unterminated s
```

Eventhough it sounds very easy (and should be), I litterly can't find an answer for it anywhere. I have a text file and a variable with exactly what I want to remove. But I can't find out how to use this to remove the text from the file using the value of the variable.

---

This worked:

```
perl -i -00pe 'BEGIN{$pat = shift}; s/\Q$pat\E//' "$oldvalue" advancedplexapivar.txt
```

My questions for Steeldriver:

1. If you don't want to, it's okay but if you have time, could you explain the command?
2. I'm now experiencing gaps between the different users (`[...]`), sometimes 2 or 3 empty lines between them. Is there a command like `sed -E "s|\n{2,}|\n|g"`? I ofcourse tried that, but it didn't work.

```
[Aimee]
...
sonarrport="8005"



[Dee]
...
sonarrport="8005"
```

needs to become

```
[Aimee]
...
sonarrport="8005"

[Dee]
...
sonarrport="8005"
```

The command is allowed to have effect on the complete file so in the complete file, there is only one empty line at the time "allowed".

Comment: May you please format your question and "source code" in a appropriate way? Every file should be shown with its own `code box` and comments like title should not be included in that `code box` but outside of it, probably with formated text.

Comment: @paladin yeah now that I look back at it, I could have done better. I edited the question

Comment: @Cas you can squeeze blank lines with `cat -s file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try perl, in *paragraph mode*:

```
perl -00pe 'BEGIN{$pat = shift}; s/\Q$pat\E//' "$oldvalue" advancedplexapi.txt
```

Comment: It works.. almost. I get the correct output, but I get it inside the terminal instead of writing the output to the file. I already did `... COMMAND > advancedplexapivar.txt` to write the output to the file but the file just becomes completly empty. I basically need `sed -i`. Where do I need to put the `-i`, as the `s/\Q$pat\E//` part looks alot like sed.

Comment: think `perl` support `-i` too. (man perlrun)

Comment: adding `-i` as in `perl -00pe -i ...` didn't work. Gave me the correct output again, but didn't write to the file. Just outputting to the terminal.

Comment: @Cas it needs to be `perl -i -00pe '...'` or `perl -i.bak -00pe '...'` if you want a backup (the **expression** needs to come after the **-e**)

Comment: Oh well. I works now. I have two remaining questions, but I'll edit the original question to include those questions!

Answer (score 0):

The usual logical way to accomplish your task is the following.

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE=$1
SWITCH="FALSE"

while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    if [ "$LINE" == "[Dee]" ]; then
        SWITCH="TRUE"
    fi

    if [ "$LINE" == "" ]; then
        SWITCH="FALSE"
    fi

    if [ "$SWITCH" == "FALSE" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$LINE"
    fi
done < $SOURCE
```